# Convert timestamp into another date format

Tags: php

I have a date

```
  $myDate = "2017-07-31 06:12:51";
```

I wanted to convert this date into following format

```
  $result = "12/31/1969 - 07:33 PM"
```

I have used below function to convert specific date

```
  $result = date("m/d/Y - h:i A",$myDate);
```

It is converting in the format I want but everytime it is printing the below same date for differents timings.

```
  12/31/1969 - 07:33 PM
```

Which is wrong, Please suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`date()` requires the second parameter to be a Unix timestamp. Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to do this:

```
$result = date("m/d/Y - h:i A", strtotime($myDate));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/W6qKp)

`strtottime()` requires [a valid date format to work](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), but yours is so you won't have any problems.

Comment: Ha, beat me by milli seconds :)

Comment: delete my response, and put you one uped vote . Good done!